# Error after install wordpress in ubuntu 18.10.1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I try to install wordpress in VM ubuntu 18.10.1, i do everything correct but when i open the project on browser, i have this message ("***Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.***")
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tQmv.jpg)

enverenment: 
VM ubuntu 18.10.1
PHP 7.2.20
Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu)

I need your help please
thank you

Comment: the error is pretty clear. You miss the php mysql extesion. You have to install it with apt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql extension :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

And then restart apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```